# How to inject views of Fragments used in PagerAdapter with Dagger?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am developing an application that requires Tabs.
It has an idea of a "Category" of place, eg Cafe, Park, etc. and each category is a Tab and each have a very similar structure of its contents and views.

So I created a `PagerAdapter` that contains a multiple instance of the fragment I created. My problem is how to inject views in each instance of fragments using dagger.

Comment: It may helps https://alexdunn.org/2017/07/11/android-kotlin-create-a-tablayout/

Comment: Hi @Pinki, I dont think the article you gave is using dagger.

Comment: Are you using any specific architecture?

Comment: I am guessing you might be able to do it by creating separate subcomponents. Sharing some code pieces of your structure might help creating a proper answer though.